# Book about amnesiac on planet with gigantic aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m trying to find out the title of a sci-fi book that I read about fifteen years ago. I can’t remember the author or any of the characters’ names. What I do remember:

- the male protagonist suffers from amnesia
- He finds himself on a world where humans survive in an underground colony
- The colony’s leader is called the Captain, who rules assisted by the Crew.
- The planet is  inhabited by gigantic aliens, who lead a very normal suburban life, mostly uninterested in the (to them) ant like humans.
- The protagonist joins a team that has to venture into the world above to help the colony survive. I think they went up to forage and such.
- Because humans lead their whole lives underground, few of them are able to cope with the open air, where there is no roof above them.
- The protagonist, during one of those away missions, shoots the child alien in the eye. I think this prompts mother alien to put the kettle on to chuck the hot water on the human colony.
- the book ends with a human spaceship appearing, which saves saves everyone because they are able to communicate with the aliens.
- It turns out the protagonist is the spaceship’s captain (not sure here), who got lost during a reconnaissance mission with a shuttle.
- The colony is descended from a spaceship that crash landed a long time ago.

As for when it was written: I only remember the blurb saying that the author intended to continue writing sci-fi, even if the Americans and Soviets landed on Mars!

**Edit: ** It was a paperback. I can’t remember much about the cover. I do have this image in my head of one of the gigantic aliens. It is standing upright and is wearing a (flower?) dress, but its features are otherwise insectlike. Updated the original post accordingly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to remember any details of the cover art?  Was it an e-book, a paperback or hardcover?

Comment: Ah, sorry: it was a paperback. I can’t remember the cover, which I think means that the cover was quite boring, i.e. no images.

Comment: During this underground sojourn did they at one point hold a dance but a 'rat' scuttled across the dancefloor (it was actually an insect but they called it a rat)

Comment: Does the alien child attempt to pick up the protagonist, and the protagonist shoots it in self defense? I ask because I have a nagging but vague memory of a scene like this.

Comment: @JohnRennie yes, now that you mention it: I believe so!

Comment: @DannyMcG not sure about the dance, but the rat does ring a bell.

Comment: @DavidW I might remember something more about a cover. I have this image in my head of one of the gigantic aliens. It is standing upright and is wearing a (flower?) dress, but its features are otherwise insectlike. Updated the original post accordingly.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's the same mystery story as this (unanswered) question on another site.....https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/567734/#post-2587193